# SSIS Log file, dynamic file path and access denied error

Tags: ssis, bids

I have a parent package where I set a variable pointing to a folder where I want to write the execution log of the package. This parent package executes child packages and set value for child's variables too.

In child packages the package logging is stetted up and the connection string to log file is built with the expression:

```
[User::LogFolder] + "\\" + [System::PackageName] + ".log"
```

But my package always fail in the first step with this message:

```
Error: 0xC001404B at Child Package, Log provider "SSIS log provider for Text files": The SSIS logging provider has failed to open the log. Error code: 0x80070005. Acces denied.
```

The error happens inside BIDS. If I set the path to the log file statically to the same path, then it runs without problems, so it doesn't seems to be a permissions problem. Any suggestion on how to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit: The problem seems to happen because [User::LogFolder] value is obtained from parent package, and when the package tries to open the log the values have not been passed yet, causing the error. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: As per the error it states 'Access Denied' which is clearly permissions problem.  Put a break point in child package and check the variable value for LogFolder.

Comment: @Sreedhar Thanks for your comment. I already verified the path and it's pointing to the right location. Unfortunately, as I said in the post, if I set the variable to the same static value that the expression evaluates to, the error goes away.

Comment: @Sreedhar I guess I found the reason of the error, but don't know how to solve. My package is a child package and the variable [User::LogFolder] is filled from parent. The problem is that when package starts, there is no value yet for [User::LogFolder] but package start event is been reported, and the expression can't be evaluated.

Comment: Check this: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/mikedavis/ssis/155/passing-variable-values-from-parent-package-to-child-ssis

Comment: @Sreedhar I know how to pass variables from parent to child. The problem is that the package tries to use them BEFORE they are initialized to build the log path, causing the error. Y ended hard coding LogFolder value in child package, but wish to find an elegant solution for this, like forcing the log provider to wait for var initialization before trying to write anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. For the records, the problem was that [User::LogFolder] value is obtained from parent package. And the child package was trying to write to the log before the variable value were filled, causing the error.
I solved it hardcoding the log value in the package. :-(